# Wi-Fi disabled after suspend/restart in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, suspend

Every time I wake my notebook up from suspend or I turn it on again, Wi-Fi is disabled and I have to connect manually by clicking "Enable Wi-Fi". How to set up to enable Wi-Fi automatically on resume or boot as it previously was?

Comment: I'm affected by the same issue since recently. It could be some regression in updated software?

Answer (score 2):

I had the sme problem on ubuntu 15 I fixed it this way

```
sudo gedit /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wifi-restart
```

then paste

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
    resume|thaw)
        service network-manager restart;;
esac
```

Save the file and close it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar issue by running:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
sudo service network-manager start
```

And

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Sources:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1622883
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1505217